# How to temporarily disable button after click in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin.forms

I am making a poll application in `Xamarin Forms` and I want users to be able to vote just one time/day. On the UI page, I created an ImageButton and I want the user to be able to click it just one time/day. I tried using a Timer, and tried to test it for 5 seconds intervals. The Application disabled the button when I first clicked it but after 5 seconds I could click it all over again and it doesn't disable the button.

```
private void ImageButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   this.IsEnabled = false;
   Timer aTimer = new Timer();
   aTimer.Interval = 5000; //ms
   aTimer.Enabled = true;
   aTimer.Elapsed += ATimer_Elapsed;
}

private void ATimer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
  this.IsEnabled = true;       
}
```

I saw that the application enters the `ImageButton_Clicked` function all the time but it does not execute `this.IsEnabled=false`;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the application is doing what you have told it.

`this.IsEnabled` is working, but **this** is referencing the page itself. If you want on click to disable the button that has fired event, then you need this:

```cs
private void ImageButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (sender is Button button)
    {
        button.IsEnabled = false;
        // the rest of the logic
    }
}
```

Here, we are casting the `sender` as a Xamarin.Forms.**Button**. If the cast is successful, meaning if the sender is our button, then we can disable it.

If you don't want to cast it or you want do use the button reference in another method (like you are enabling it again), the simply set the button with a `Name` property in the xml like so:

```xml
<Button 
    x:Name="myButton"
    Clicked="ImageButton_Clicked" />
```

Then, you can use it in the code-behind in the `ATimer_Elapsed` method like this:

```cs
private void ATimer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => { myButton.IsEnabled = true; });
}
```

Edit: It is **very** important to invoke the `IsEnabled = true` here on the **main/UI** thread, since the timer logic is being done on a background thread.

Comment: I tried naming the button and writing `myButton.IsEnabled=true;` as you said but it still doesn't work. I tried this before, but the result was the same, it disables for the first time and after I can click it all over again without it being disabled.

Comment: Of course that it does. After each click on the button, you are starting a new timer, which will enable the button again after 5 seconds. This is what your code is suppose to do with its current implementation.

Comment: `private void ImageButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(sender is Button button)
            {
                button.IsEnabled = false;
                Timer aTimer = new Timer();
                aTimer.Interval = 5000; 
                aTimer.Enabled = true;
                aTimer.Elapsed += ATimer_Elapsed;
            }
        }

        private void ATimer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            b.IsEnabled = true;
        }`  this is my code, but it doesn't work as i wanted

Comment: Yes, this code will work. What is does, when you click on a button, will be: 1) disable the button; 2) Start a timer for 5 seconds; 3) When the 5 seconds have elapsed, the button will be enabled again. If this is what you want to achieve, then yes - this will work.

Comment: 1) disable the button; 2) Start a timer for 5 seconds; 3) When the 5 seconds have elapsed, the button will be enabled again. And after this all over again. Maybe I didn't write the code as you said, but it is not working. It does the job the first time, then I can press as many times on the button as I want and it won't happen anything. Sorry if I am being a dummy, it is my first encounter with this. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I got it. Sorry for my misunderstanding. I have updated my answer above. Please see the last method, it is very important that the IsEnabled=true is being invoked on the main thread. This way you will enable back your button.

Comment: ` private void ImageButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                this.IsEnabled = false;
                Timer aTimer = new Timer();
                aTimer.Interval = 5000; //ms
                aTimer.Enabled = true;
                aTimer.Elapsed += ATimer_Elapsed;
  
        }

        private void ATimer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("X");
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => { myButton.IsEnabled = true; });
        } ` and in the xaml i named my button : myButton.The app still doesn't work

Comment: It is not working, because you keep disabling the button with this.IsEnabled = false. Like I mentioned, THIS is point to the page itself, not the button, change it to myButton.IsEnabled = false and everything will work. :)

Comment: Glad to have helped. :)

Comment: Is there a way to keep this thing going even if I switch pages?

Comment: It depends on what you actually want to keep going. The timer should keep going, even if you navigate forward and then backwards to the page. If you want, you can extract the timer logic to some more common place - like a wrapper page/view model or even in App.xaml.cs, if the logic requires it. If you can't seem to make it work, you can ask another question, where you can describe in details & in code what exactly was your thought.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code.
I hope it is working.

```
    private void ImageButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
           var btn = sender as ImageButton;
           btn.IsEnabled = false;
           Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), () =>
           {

                    btn.IsEnabled = true;
                    return false;
           });
    }
```

Comment: It gives me this error
Error CS1643 Not all code paths return a value in lambda expression of type 'Func<bool>'

Comment: This is not a good approach, since the Device.StartTimer expects a callback Func<bool> If you return true, the timer will keep recurring, which is not what the OP's asking. For reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.device.starttimer?view=xamarin-forms

Comment: Now i have return false and according to you now it is not  recurring.

Answer (score 0):

The answer for this question is a bit long, but simple.

- Create a custom button component because XF doesn't disable button and change the color properly (at least for me):

  - XAML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<Button xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
        x:Class="LindeGctMobileApplication.Modules.CustomComponents.CustomButton.CustomButtonView"
        FontAttributes="Bold"
        TextColor="{StaticResource LightTextPrimary}"
        FontSize="20"
        TextTransform="Uppercase"
        CornerRadius="20"
        WidthRequest="200"
        HorizontalOptions="Center" />
```

- Code behind:

```cs
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class CustomButtonView
{
   #region constructors

   public CustomButtonView()
   {
      InitializeComponent();
      BackgroundColor = Color.Blue;

      Clicked += (_, args) =>
      {
         if (IsEnabled) Command?.Execute(args);
      };
   }

   #endregion

   #region Command

   public new static readonly BindableProperty CommandProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
            nameof(Command),
            typeof(ICommand),
            typeof(CustomButtonView));

   public new ICommand? Command
   {
      get => (ICommand)GetValue(CommandProperty);
      set => SetValue(CommandProperty, value);
   }


   #endregion
        
   #region IsEnabled

   public new static readonly BindableProperty IsEnabledProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
            nameof(IsEnabled),
            typeof(bool),
            typeof(CustomButtonView),
            true,
            propertyChanged: (bindable, _, newValue) =>
   {
      var component = (CustomButtonView)bindable;

      if ((bool)newValue)
      {
         component.BackgroundColor = Color.Blue;
      }
      else
      {
         component.BackgroundColor = Color.Gray;
      }
   });

   public new bool IsEnabled
   {
      get => (bool)GetValue(IsEnabledProperty);

      set => SetValue(IsEnabledProperty, value);
   }

   #endregion
}
```

- Add the CustomButton inside your screen XAML:

```xml
<customButton:CustomButtonView Text="Your Custom Button"
                               Command="{Binding ClickCommand}"
                               IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabled}"/>
```

- Create the following static class to debounce your buttons clicks, the user can click multiple times and the method will compute the time after last click, it will be used later:

```
public static class CustomTaskExtension
{
   #region fields

   private static int _last;

   #endregion

   public static void Debounce(CancellationTokenSource throttleCts, double debounceTimeMs, Action action)
   {
      var current = Interlocked.Increment(ref _last);
      Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(debounceTimeMs), throttleCts.Token).ContinueWith(task =>
         {
            if (current == _last) action();
               task.Dispose();
         });
    }
}
```

- Add the following property in your ViewModel:

```cs
private bool _isEnabled;

public bool IsEnabled
{
   get => _isEnabled;
   set
   {
      OnPropertyChanged("IsEnabled");
      _isEnabled = value;
   }
}
```

- Add the following command to your button:

```cs
public ICommand ClickCommand => new Command(() => Click());

private void Click()
{
   // disable the button
   IsEnabled = false;
   
   // the debounce is used to enable the button after 5s of the last call of this method
   CustomTaskExtension.Debounce(new CancellationTokenSource(), 5000, () =>
   {
      IsEnabled = true;
   });
}
```

That's all Folks!